# Does rate of latent heat transfer of steam to another fluid increase with increasing temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I know rate of sensible heat transfer is dependent on temperature difference, but I haven't found much information on the *rate* of latent heat transfer of steam with respect to temperature. Take, for example, the following 2 heat exchangers:

HEX 1: 150C sat'd steam on one side, 100C/1atm process liquid on the other

HEX 2: 120C sat'd steam on one side, 100C/1atm process liquid on the other

Assumptions:

- Both HEX's have the same heat transfer area
- No heat loss to surroundings

Let's say that HEX 1 is sized such that based on the flow rates of both fluids, there is an isothermal and complete transfer of latent heat of the steam to the process liquid.

1. Assuming the same mass flow rates and HEX sizing, will HEX 2 transfer its latent heat slower (resulting in incomplete latent heat transfer and uncondensed steam leaving HEX 2) because there's less of a temperature difference compared to HEX 1?
2. Is it virtually instantaneous so practically not dependent on temperature?
3. Overarching question: If you need to design a HEX with saturated steam as the heat transfer media and a 100C process fluid, is there any advantage to using higher pressure saturated steam (i.e. 150C vs 120C or even 105C)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Well off my turf here, but if the steam in $HEX_2$ is lower temperature then won't it be quicker to condense (other things being equal) because it has less excess thermal energy to lose before the liquid-phase bonds can begin to form?

Comment: @MartinCR Not quite. When I say saturated steam, I mean it's at a temperature and pressure where any loss of energy would lead directly to phase change (so HEX 1 steam is higher pressure than HEX 2). So, with respect to excess sensible heat, there is none in either scenario.

Comment: Ah! Thanks I've leaned something :-)

Comment: Hmmm - I'd tend to agree that with $HEX_1$ the rate of energy transfer would be higher because of the greater difference in temperature; so the condensation would occur faster.

Comment: Why don't you just run calculations for a few sample cases (assuming constant overall heat transfer coefficient) and see how it plays out.

Comment: @ChetMiller My confusion stems from how to apply a heat transfer coefficient when all you're doing is transferring latent heat. If you assume a constant heat transfer coefficient, then yes, clearly the higher temp steam should have a 50/20 deltaT advantage in terms of accomplished energy transfer. But the question is largely about how to calculate heat transfer coefficient when condensing steam, so I don't think it makes sense to assume its constant in both scenarios? If I'm missing something and you could elaborate, that would be appreciated.

Comment: See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena for estimates of heat transfer coefficients for boiling and condensing steam.  In my judgement, the effect of the heat transfer coefficient differences is going to be much smaller than the effect of the temperature differences.